# Use data from IR sensor to build a costmap

Tags: navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, costmap, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working on Turtlebot2. I will use cover for my robot, so I moved Kinect to the front of the robot to make a smaller holes in cover. But now I have a blind area in front of the robot, between 0 and 45 cm. I decided to mount some IR sensors. I made transformation for (yet) only one sensor

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "irring_tf");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Rate r(100);

  tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;

  while(n.ok()){
    broadcaster.sendTransform(
      tf::StampedTransform(
        tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), tf::Vector3(0.135, 0.0, 0.2)),
        ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "base_irring"));
    r.sleep();
  }
}
```

next I receive data from sensor and publish it as a LaserScan message (I create two points from one sensor, because I will use this code for more sensors, in this case it is no matter)

```
    ros::Time scan_time = ros::Time::now(); 
    sensor_msgs::LaserScan scan;
    scan.header.stamp = scan_time;
    scan.header.frame_id = "base_irring";
    scan.angle_min = -0.05;     //rad
    scan.angle_max = 0.05;      //rad
    scan.angle_increment = 0.10 / num_readings;     //rad
    scan.time_increment = (1 / laser_frequency) / (num_readings);   //sec
    scan.range_min = 0.20;       //meters
    scan.range_max = 1.15;     //meters

    scan.ranges.resize(num_readings);
    scan.intensities.resize(num_readings);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < num_readings; ++i){
      scan.ranges[i] = atof(buf) / 100.0;   //data from arduino
//      scan.intensities[i] = 1; //data from arduino
    }

    scan_pub.publish(scan);
```

It works, I can visualize data in correct place using Rviz (white line is data from Kinect, red dots data are taken from IR sensor)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woMNOnIB2bo&list=UUclHPTMTlaW_M55gYhp_ylQ

Next I want to use this data to build costmap, so I add to costmap_common_params.yaml my irring_scan, changed map_type from voxel to costmap (because I want to clear obstacles detected by IR sensors by Kinect, I want to use 2d map)

```
max_obstacle_height: 0.60  # assume something like an arm is mounted on top of the robot

# Obstacle Cost Shaping (http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/inflation)
# robot_radius: 0.20  # distance a circular robot should be clear of the obstacle (kobuki: 0.18)
footprint: [[-0.25, 0.25], [0.25, 0.25], [0.25, -0.25], [-0.25, -0.25]]  # if the robot is not circular

map_type: costmap

obstacle_layer:
  enabled:              true
  max_obstacle_height:  0.6
  origin_z:             0.0
  z_resolution:         0.2
  z_voxels:             2
  unknown_threshold:    15
  mark_threshold:       0
  combination_method:   1
  track_unknown_space:  true    #true needed for disabling global path planning through unknown space
  obstacle_range: 2.5
  raytrace_range: 3.0
  origin_z: 0.0
  z_resolution: 0.2
  z_voxels: 2
  publish_voxel_map: false
  observation_sources:  scan bump irring_scan
  scan:
    data_type: LaserScan
    topic: scan
    marking: true
    clearing: true
    min_obstacle_height: 0.25
    max_obstacle_height: 0.35
  irring_scan:
    data_type: LaserScan
    sensor_frame: base_link
    topic: irring_scan
    marking: true
    clearing: true
    min_obstacle_height: 0.25
    max_obstacle_height: 0.35
  bump:
    data_type: PointCloud2
    topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud
    marking: true
    clearing: false
    min_obstacle_height: 0.0
    max_obstacle_height: 0.15
  # for debugging only, let's you see the entire voxel grid

#cost_scaling_factor and inflation_radius were now moved to the inflation_layer ns
inflation_layer:
  enabled:              true
  cost_scaling_factor:  5.0  # exponential rate at which the obstacle cost drops off (default: 10)
  inflation_radius:     0.5  # max. distance from an obstacle at which costs are incurred for planning paths.

static_layer:
  enabled:              true
```

Next I changed in local_costmap_params.yaml from

```
name: obstacle_layer,      type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
```

to

```
name: obstacle_layer,      type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
```

I did the same for global_costmap_params.yaml

But as you can see below
[image: http://i.imgur.com/yfoARJS.png]

costmap is built only using data from Kinect, there is no obstacles marked around IR points.

I'll be very glad if you tell me what I should add, change or remove to get it working.

Edit:

Solution is to set z_voxels variable to 3, because we use 3 sources of data, not 2. You can also play with correct obstacle heights.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199737/use-data-from-ir-sensor-to-build-a-costmap/) by [dawid.wolski](https://answers.ros.org/users/21159/dawid.wolski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-03**:
Hi, so with regards to the "Edit", did you finally successfully implemented the mapping with IR sensor(s)? may i ask what IR sensors (make and model) did you use? im trying to practice the same implementation on my Turtlebot. Thanks!

**Comment by [dawid.wolski](https://answers.ros.org/users/21159/dawid.wolski/) on 2015-06-10**:
Hi, sorry for my late response, but now I'm not working with the robot. Yes, my mapping using IR sensors and other sensors works well. I use 9 Sharp GP2Y0A21YK or similar sensors. For me the most important parameter is the minimal range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, we added both an IR ring and a sonar ring to the turtlebot. Code for the sonar ring using and Arduino Mega can be found [here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/tree/master/thorp_boards). I use [Bosch drivers](https://github.com/corot/bosch_drivers/blob/master/adc_driver/src/adc_driver.cpp) to interface with arduino. There's also code to read Sharp IR (is basically the same, apart that the sonars need to be triggered). And 3D models to nicely mount a ring on the TB2 can be downloaded [here](http://kobuki.yujinrobot.com/home-en/documentation/howtos/ir-sensors-ring/)

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-06-17**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2015-06-18**:
I have changed the way I interact with the arduino, because as I read 15 sensors, using a Bosch driver for each one makes reading very slow. I have now wrote my own very simple arduino firmware that collects all data and send through serial port. The driver just read it at convert into ROS Range msg